# question mark add to url when click login

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

this code in the first time clicked take me to localhost:8080//? it should take me directly to localhost:8080//admin.html why this happens ??

```
 $("#admin-login").click(function(){

    var data = {"username": $("#adminUserName").val(), "password": $("#adminPassword").val()};
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/admin/login",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success:function (data) {
            if(data.success)
            {
                window.location= "/admin.html";
            }
            else
            {
                alert(data.message)
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Take a look at your browser debugging tools, especially the timeline. Maybe `admin.html` does not exist and what you are looking at is the the page **after** you were redirected by the server.

Comment: no its run correctly after that , sometime its open and sometimes dont

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.location.href = "/admin.html";
```

sometimes window.location create errors. This solved a problem in Typescript redirecting error.